# Compilation takes more than 15 seconds || Babel - Gulpfile - es6 - rollup bundler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compilation, gulp, babeljs

I have got a very long compilation time and I try to figure it out. 
The compilation have to work for the SASS and for the javascript es6 files and for the handlebars template.

There are two parts on my web application. The first one is the **nodeJs server** and the other part is the **web application** using the **nodeJS server**.

[See there a screenshot from my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkugr.png)

Any thoughts on how to help me on this?

tree :

```
/index.js
/package.json
/gulpfile.babel.json
/public/
       src/
           script/*
           styles/*
           template/*

/dist
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": *****",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "****",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "google-auth-library": "^0.10.0",
    "googleapis": "^20.1.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.10",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.15",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^1.3.5",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "backbone-associate": "0.0.13",
    "backbone.localstorage": "^1.1.16",
    "backbone.marionette": "^3.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "gsap": "^1.19.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-declare": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-define-module": "^0.1.5",
    "gulp-file": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-handlebars": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-wrap": "^0.13.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.10",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.7.1",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-json": "^2.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

gulfile.babel.js :

```js
import gulp from 'gulp';
import sass from 'gulp-ruby-sass';
import { rollup } from 'rollup';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import plumber from 'gulp-plumber';
import file from 'gulp-file';
import filter from 'gulp-filter';
import rename from 'gulp-rename';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import handlebars from 'gulp-handlebars';
import wrap from 'gulp-wrap';
import declare from 'gulp-declare';
import merge from 'merge-stream';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import defineModule from 'gulp-define-module';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';


import {name} from './package.json';
const srcPath = 'public/src/';

function bundle(opts) { // very long ...  (12s) 
  return rollup({
    entry: srcPath + "scripts/" + name + '.js',
    plugins: [
      json(),
      builtins(),
      nodeResolve(),
     commonjs(),
      babel({
        // sourceMaps: true,
        presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}]],
        babelrc: false
      })
    ]
  }).then(bundle => {
    return _generate(bundle);
  }).then(gen => {
    gen.code += '\n//# sourceMappingURL=' + gen.map.toUrl();
    return gen;
  });
}

function _generate(bundle) { // long too (4s)
  return bundle.generate({
    format: 'iife',
    moduleName: 'ATalks',
    sourceMap: true
  });
}

function compileScripts(buildPath) {
  return bundle().then(gen => {
    return file(name + '.js', gen.code, {src: true})
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath))
      .pipe(filter(['**', '!**/*.js.map']))
      .pipe(rename(name + '.min.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath));
  });
}

function compileScriptsLight(buildPath) {
  return bundle().then(gen => {
    return file(name + '.js', gen.code, {src: true})
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPath))
  });
}

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return sass(srcPath+'styles/all.scss')
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/styles'))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(done) {
  return compileScripts('public/dist/');
});

gulp.task('scriptsLight', function(done) {
  return compileScriptsLight('public/dist/');
});

gulp.task('templates', function(done){
  gulp.src(['public/src/templates/*.hbs'])
    .pipe(handlebars({
      handlebars: require('handlebars')
    }))
    .pipe(defineModule('es6', {
   require: {
    Handlebars: "handlebars/runtime"
   }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/src/templates'));

    runSequence('scripts', done);
});

gulp.task('move', function() {
 gulp.src([srcPath+"*.html", srcPath+"images/**", srcPath+"fonts/**"], {base: srcPath }).pipe(gulp.dest("public/dist/"));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  browserSync.init(null, {
      proxy: "http://localhost:3000",
      files: ["public/dist/**/*.*"],
      port: 7000
  });
 gulp.watch(srcPath+'/**/*.js',['scriptsLight']);
 gulp.watch(srcPath+'/**/*.hbs',['templates']);
 gulp.watch(srcPath+'/**/*.scss',['sass']);
  gulp.watch(srcPath+'*.html',['move']);
  gulp.watch(srcPath+'/images/**',['move']);
  gulp.watch(srcPath+'/fonts/**',['move']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['templates', 'scripts', 'sass', 'move']);
```

.babelrc :

```js
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```